# Calculate sum for m=1 to n in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have vector `A` and vector `B` - columns of digits in the Excel spreadsheet.

How can I calculate vector `C` in excel where
`C(n) = SUM m=1 to n (Am * Bn-m+1)` ?

Comment: Can you further clarify your question and tells us what you tried already ? And an example of how you represent vectors A & B in Excel ? A screenshot would be good, or a table in the question.

Comment: A & B — columns with digits in Excel. For example A(100; 104; 112; 98; ...; 101) and B(0,9; 0,8; 0,94; 0,74; ...; 0,98).

Comment: I guess an array function should be used here (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) but it's not clear how to iterate throught the m=1  to n

Comment: Is A1 the first value in the array (100), and A2 the second (104) ? And if so, then C(n) is not a vector (array), but a single value ?

Comment: Cn = Summation Am*Bn-m+1 for m = 1 to n.

Comment: C1 = A1 * B1; C2 = A1*B2 + A2*B1; C3 = A1*B3 + A2*B2 + A3*B1

Comment: I will formulate an answer with using a helper column (basically to reverse the B vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a helper column (in column D), I think the answer is quite trivial, and you don't even need array formula:

- Reverse vector B : formula in cell `D1`, which you then drag down until the end of vector B : `=INDEX($B$1:$B$20,COUNTA($B$1:$B$20)+ROW($B$1:$B$20)-ROW(),1)`
- Calculate vector C : `=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:A1,$D$1:D1)` (please note the mix of absolute and relative cell references). Put this in cell `C1` and then copy down to the end of vector A & B (I assume that they must have the same number of values).

For completeness, you also can reverse the vector B on the fly (i.e. in a single formula). The overall formula gets then:
`=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:A1, N(OFFSET($B$1:B1,ROW(B1)-ROW($B$1:B1),0))`
So you put this in `C1` and then copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer submitted by Peter K. (cannot comment yet):

Calculate vector C: `=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:A1,OFFSET($D$1:D1,COUNTA($A$1:$A$20)-COUNTA($A$1:A1),0))`

I believe this will calculate as the OP had asked for.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that as well. I think you have to wrap the offset with a `N()`. And I prefer using the `ROW()` function, but it works the same obviously.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!